# Why do the Endless all have names starting with the letter "D"?

Tags: the-sandman

I've realized that in English all *The Endless* have names that start with the letter "D": Death, Delight/Delirium, Desire, Despair, Destiny, Destruction, and Dream.

Is this just a coincidence?

Comment: Kai'kul and Morpheus don't start with D. It appears to just be a coincidence of how English works

Comment: @Valorum Morpheus and Kai'kul are just other names for Dream.

Comment: @Raj - Dream is just another name for The Sandman ;-)

Comment: Note that the name Kai'Kul predates the English language (and the word "Dream") by nearly 7000 years.

Comment: Out of universe it's clearly not a coincidence. Gaiman could have named them Mortality, Lust, Sadness, Fate, War, and Sleep. He probably chose the names he did to make things poetic and clever. Are you asking for an in-universe answer? There may not be any in-universe answer that makes sense, since the Endless existed before the English language existed, but maybe they choose their own names for languages when those languages arise and they try to be alliterative?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Sandman/comments/1axbcqm/endkless_names/krnocb0/ But I cannot find a source for that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hy Bender notes in *The Sandman Companion* that Gaiman's original concept started out with three brothers, *"death, sleep, and ?"*. Sleep later changed to Dream, Death became a sister, and ? turned to Destiny, who was already a character at DC.

Gaiman himself later elaborates (on p. 235):

> Once I had Dream, Death, and Destiny, I went, "Oh! All their names begin with the letter *D*. Well, I'll continue that for each additional member of the family." I never made a big point of it, because it was fun to just drop the name of each new member of the Endless into the series and allow people to gradually notice.

It should be noted that, as Gaiman points, none of those are *names* per se, since an anthropomorphic personification of an elemental concept cannot meaningfully possess a name. Rather, those are descriptions that vaguely outline the respective functions they are responsible for.

Another interesting way of looking at those comes from Destruction, when he talks with Morpheus about their respective natures and notes that they could as well be defining the opposite of their "name"-sakes, e.g. Dream is the one who defines reality, for everything that doesn't belong in his domain, is, by definition, real.

Comment: And they also have other names that they go by. Morpheus/The Sandman/Fate/Kai'kul/Change, etc etc